# Android: App crashes on my phone but not on Emulator during IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

New to android and have a situation where my app does not crash on the Emulator, but it crashes on the phone.  So I don't get a chance to see what's causing the app to crash.

The app runs an IntentService that continually looks in a folder of images to:
  - upload new images to my server
  - copy the image to another folder
  - delete the image from the original folder
  - return to look for the next image

I have setup my app with a minimal UI.  Just 2 activities: 1. main activity, and 2. activity to set folder preferences.  There are 2 buttons on the main activity: 1. to start the service, and 2. to stop the service.

When I start the service and copy a image to the designated folder, the image is uploaded to my server and then moved to the designated move-to phone folder - great.  But I guess as the process returns to look into the folder for the next file, something happens that forces the app to crash.

IntentService:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class incomingPicListener extends IntentService {
    Bitmap photoCapturedBitmap;
    private static final String RESULT_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String URL_SAVE_IMAGE = "http://.....php";
    Boolean imgsaved;

    String fileFound;

    public incomingPicListener() {

        super("incomingPicListener");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid){
        Toast.makeText(incomingPicListener.this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("Service Started");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startid);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("Service Stopped");
        Toast.makeText(incomingPicListener.this, "Service stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences folderPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FolderPrefs", 0);

        final String savedFolder = folderPrefs.getString("FolderInput", "<Empty>");
        final String savedTargetPhoneFolder = folderPrefs.getString("TargetPhoneFolder", "<Empty>");

        synchronized (this) {
            int count = 0;
            while (count<10) {
                try {
                    wait(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                File dir = new File(savedFolder);
                File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        fileFound=name;
                        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".JPG");
                    }
                });
                String filepath = savedFolder+"/"+fileFound;
                File check = new File(savedFolder+"/"+fileFound);

                if ((!check.isDirectory()) && fileFound != null) {
                    String imagepath= savedFolder + "/" + fileFound;
                    if(setupImage(imagepath)){
                        moveFile(imagepath, savedTargetPhoneFolder + "/" + fileFound);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(incomingPicListener.this, "Upload failed: " +imagepath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


            }

        }
    }

    public boolean setupImage(String imgpath){

        photoCapturedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgpath);

        String str = getStringImage(photoCapturedBitmap);
        HashMap HashMap = new HashMap();
        HashMap.put("name",fileFound);
        HashMap.put("image", str);
        String result = sendPostRequest(URL_SAVE_IMAGE, HashMap);
        if (result.toLowerCase().contains(RESULT_SUCCESS)){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap paramBitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream localByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        paramBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, localByteArrayOutputStream);
        return Base64.encodeToString(localByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), 0);
    }
    public void moveFile(String origFile, String trgFile){
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try{

            File afile =new File(origFile);
            File bfile =new File(trgFile);

            inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            afile.delete();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        URL url;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream (conn.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String response;
                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(response);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
enter code here
```

Main Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView status;
    Intent loader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurrentState);
        Button btnPref = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFolderLocations);
        Button btnEnable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEnableProcess);
        Button btnDisable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDisableProcess);


        btnPref.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEnable.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDisable.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bFolderLocations:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FolderPref.class));
                break;
            case R.id.bEnableProcess:
                startService(this);
                status.setText("Enabled");
                break;
            case R.id.bDisableProcess:
                stopService(this);
                status.setText("Disabled");
                break;
        }


    }

    public void startService(MainActivity view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,incomingPicListener.class);
        startService(intent);

    }

    public void stopService (MainActivity view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,incomingPicListener.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }
}
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.imgloader..." >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FolderPref"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_folder_pref" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".incomingPicListener"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".DirectoryChooserActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_directory_chooser" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Would be great to see the crash message.

Comment: Am I able to see that on the phone?

Comment: If your phone is connected then yes you can see everything whats going in Logcat in Android Studio.

Comment: I'd have to figure out how to use the phone instead of the emulator with my iMac.  Worth the time to figure it out though.  Thank you.

Comment: @HectorReyes Of which SDK level is your phone? How about your emulator?

Comment: I was using 23 but had to go back because the listFiles() method was returning null when in fact there were files in the folders.  Found someone who had the same issue recently and they had reverted to 22 which I did and the method worked again.

Comment: When using a phone to run the app you will see the logcat in Android Studio the same way as if you're using the emulator as far as you keep the phone connected to your iMac via USB. Have a look at the trace shown and post it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the IntentService to your manifest?

```
<service
    android:name="com.package.name.MyIntentService"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to debug using my phone on AS.  And the problem is the global variable I used for the fileFound - I didn't reset it and so when the process looped around, it was trying to load the same file again - except it doesn't exist because I moved it.  So I need to set fileFound = null after I delete it from the original folder.  Thank you all for your input!